# How to promisify your own javascript api which uses another promisified api with Bluebird?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm struggling with this a bit. I want to build an abstraction layer over a database driver module in node. I've already promisified the driver module by doing the following:

```
var sql = Promise.promisifyAll(require('sql-driver'));
```

Then within my own js file I want to wrap queries like so:

```
function query(queryString, transaction) {
   sql.connectAsync(config).then(function() {

      var req = new sql.Request(transaction);
      req.queryAsync(queryString).then(function(resultSet)) {
          console.log(resultSet);
      });
   });
}
```

How can I promisify (using bluebird) so that my query function is also promisified and returns a promise or thenable?

**Update:**

I want my wrapper method to also be promisified so that the user can do something like this:

```
var myDbWrapper = require('my-db-wapper');
function getData() {
    myDbWrapper.startTransaction()
    .then(function(transaction) {
        return myDbWrapper.query('select 1 as number', transaction);
     })
    .then(function(resultSet) {
        console.log(resultSet);
     }).
    .catch(function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
}
```

I'm sure this isn't working code, just trying to convey the idea. Also, this example only shows one query and doesn't show the commit method, which is also part of the wrapper. Can someone show me an example use promises to do a whole transaction with more than one query and then a 'commit' if no errors?

**Update 2:**

idbehold's example below won't allow me to do this type of thing assuming that we don't care about a transaction at this time, just a simple query:

```
myDbWrapper.query(queryString, undefined)
.then(function(recordSet) {
   console.log(recordSet);
})
.catch(function(err) {
   console.error(err);
});
```

How can I enable my query method to work that way?

**Update 3:**

I've found my answer. See below.

Comment: You don't need to "promisify", you just need to `return` the promises that you are already using.

Comment: As bergi said - promises work by return values - if you want your function to be "promisified" simply return a promise from it - that's all it takes.

Comment: Your `getData` still isn't `return`ing the myDbWrapper.startTransaction

Comment: getData is just a function for purposes of testing. My examples have little to do with getData. I'd like to know how to structure the wrapper calls e.g. query, startTransaction, as well as how to use them when making a promise-based transaction.

Answer (score 4):

Just return that promise:

```
function query(queryString, transaction) {
   return sql.connectAsync(config).then(function() {
      var req = new sql.Request(transaction);
      return req.queryAsync(queryString);
   }).then(function(resultSet)) {        // You don't actually
      console.log(resultSet);            // need this this part
      return resultSet;                  // unless you need to log
   });
}
```

Comment: But I want my wrapper to be promisified as well. This example is returning a string to the caller of query.

Comment: @u84six calling this function will return a promise.

Comment: so can you show me how the query method and startTransaction method would be used in my updated example?

Comment: @u84six well, the `query` function only takes a single parameter, so I'm not sure why you're passing `transaction` to it in your example code. Aside from that, the code you've written should work fine.

Comment: @u84six then your example code should work exactly like you'd expect it to. I don't believe you need to make any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out and it was right in front of my face. It was my lack of understanding about Promises. Most responses were correct about returning a promise, but I shouldn't return the promise I'm using, I need to create a new promise like so:

```
function query (queryString, transaction) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var req = new sql.Request(transaction);
        req.queryAsync(queryString).then(function(resultSet) {
            resolve(resultSet);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Edit, without creating a new promise:

```
function query (queryString, transaction) {
  var req = new sql.Request(transaction);
  return req.queryAsync(queryString);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do that. Wrapping the existing promise in another one is doing nothing but increasing the memory usage and lines of code.

Comment: I was unable to get your example to work. Can you give me an example of how to use the query method with your example?

Comment: I have edited your post to show you the equivalent function without creating a new promise.